# I can't find a way to access spring model not using EL

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have problem when creating JSPs to use with Spring. I put all my objects in the Model of ModelAndView, it's easy to access them using EL. The problem is to access them from usual `<% code %>`. Suppose I have a parameter from the model called "foo", is there a way to have it in a variable that I can use in standard Java code in the JSP in a `<% %>` block?

Comment: `<% code %>` isn't "usual" any more :)

Comment: what is usual then? There is a thing that I can't solve with EL

Comment: EL *is* usual. If you need scriptlets, it doesn't belong in a JSP.

Comment: I agree with you, but if I follow EL I have, in my case, to create a list of object from another list, this means a lot of allocations and that's time and memory. Given that I don't with a designer now, which is the case where EL is preferable, what's the point being so loyal to EL?

Comment: What I mean is, your controller layer should be passing data structures to the JSP in a format that's already EL-friendly. Alternatively, a custom taglib should do it. If the JSP has to restructure or transform the data itself, the controller's not doing it's job. Scriptlets are effectively deprecated in JavaEE5 and above, since there is no viable reason to use them any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to extract it from the request context:

```
<%
  Object model = request.getAttribute("modelName");
%>
```

where `modelName` is the name of the model object in the `ModelAndView`.