# JSP EL div operator - strange behavior

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, el, integer-division

I have this strange behavior in my JSP page:

I have two Integer variables `count` and `size`.

When I print the values of these variables to the page I'm getting

```
266 100
```

but when I use `${count div size}` or `${count / size}` I'm getting `2.66`.

I checked that these both are `Integer`s, also I put them to model, then retrieved in JSP (according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827775/i-cant-find-a-way-to-access-spring-model-not-using-el#4827821)) and printed class names to the JSP and they are Integers.

I know, I can write custom function, but why when that should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific case, the EL Spec mandates that both operands should be coerced to `Double` before the operator is applied.

Comment: I do not know why is this case specific, but you are right I found [here](http://jsp.java.net/spec/jsp-2_1-fr-spec-el.pdf) in chapter 1.7.2, that **Otherwise, coerce both A and B to Double and apply operator**, really strange, in mod operator Long is used.

Answer (score 1):

try `<fmt:formatNumber value="${..} maxFractionDigits="0" />`

Comment: you are correct, this works, any idea why it behaves as double value?

Comment: Beware: you might get a comma (`,`) or other characters as thousands separators! Use `<fmt:parseNumber var="nameOfVariableToWriteIntegerValueTo" integerOnly="true" type="number" value="${a / b}"/>` instead.